# I am getting error when I fetch Data from my backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am running my backend on "http://localhost:3001/" using expressjs

```
app.listen(3001, function() {
    console.log('Server is running');
});
```

my frontend on "http://localhost:3000/" using react but when i fetch data I am getting an error

```
package.json
    "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
```

```
componentDidMount() {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            fetch('/data')
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(d => console.log(d));
        };
        fetchData();
    }
```

[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eywm3.png)

Comment: Can you copy/paste the error in text instead of using a screenshot please?
And the proxy configuration use localhost:8000 but your nodejs listen on localhost:3001

Comment: See your browser's Developer tools' Network-tab. Check what that request is getting as a response.

Comment: is sending req to http://localhost:3000/data but it should be http://localhost:3001/data

Answer (score 2):

Your proxy in the package.json file on the client should be set to whatever server you are trying to connect to on the backend:

```
package.json
    "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
```

Comment: sorry, i have it in 3001

Comment: You will have to copy paste the error from the console for me to provide more help

Answer (score 0):

Does the "/data" route exist?

If it doesn't, you're trying to extract JSON from a html file and hence the error.
Remove `.then(res => res.json())` until you define the route on your server.